# How can I deactivate 'Warning: Source ID 510 was not found when attempting to remove it - GLib.source_remove(self._idle_event_id)'?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gtk, glib

When I execute

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.show()
```

(and more complex examples) I get

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/
matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py:215: Warning: 
Source ID 7 was not found when attempting to remove it
    GLib.source_remove(self._idle_event_id)
```

What causes this and how can I get rid of these warnings?

I know that I can use

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

to get rid of all warnings, but that is not what I am asking for. I want to have warnings, but none from matplotlib (especially the one from above).

Comment: I'm getting the same problem in https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/942

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with Python 3.8 / matplotlib 3.2.2

Answer (score 11):

`GLib.source_remove` was not successful because the `self.close_event()` that was executed before probably already did the job.

[This commit](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/5467c986bf79cd493248559a477a214a59201f51) should fix your problem. It is from the 23rd February. You can either wait for the next release or apply the patch manually.

Comment: Note: the commit that fixed this issue came a few days *after* the release of v1.4.3 (released on 2015-02-16 https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/releases/tag/v1.4.3), as of now (2015-07-20) the latest stable version. Thus, this issue should be fixed by the next release.

Answer (score 8):

Use `plt.close()` to fix this issue.

Comment: That is the point. Simple and efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Sorry in advance for answering an old question but I came across a similar issue after installing Python 3.6.9 and `matplotlib` via `pip` on a machine running with a Linux distro. My intent was to be able to re-run old scripts which involved `pyplot` after upgrading Python on said machine. While the scripts ran until completion and provided the expected output, I was always getting this warning:

```
/home/jefgrailet/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py:195: Warning: Source ID 8 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._idle_draw_id)
```

upon using the `savefig()` method from `pyplot` (I guess a similar problem would have occurred with the `show()` method as well). The line mentioned in the warning corresponds to this method found in `backend_gtk3.py`:

```
def destroy(self):
    #Gtk.DrawingArea.destroy(self)
    self.close_event()
    if self._idle_draw_id != 0:
        GLib.source_remove(self._idle_draw_id)
```

I looked up on the [matplotlib GitHub](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib) to check if there was a more recent version of the same script or if this problem was known, and it turns out the [current implementation](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py) of the method above only rely on the `self.close_event()` instruction, i.e., the `GLib.source_remove()` is unnecessary.

Therefore, **I commented the last 2 lines in the code above and saved the changes.** After making this edit, I could run my scripts without getting any warning. I hope this will help people encountering a similar problem.

Comment: You're right, I had the same problem when using `savefig` from `pyplot`. However, the `show` method did not produce this error. Only the `savefig` method did. Not sure if a good solution for this bug has been implemented (instead of having to hack the source code of these libraries)?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue as @CuriousLeo with Python 3.8.2 and matplotlib 3.2.1.

Comment: Note to future self: See answer by @user1959279 below to fix this issue with matplotlib3.2.1